# dynamically change css for jquery datapicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datapicker

How do I change datapicker look via jquery. I don't want to hide datapicker only ui-datepicker-calendar class.

It works:

```
   .ui-datepicker-calendar {
       display: none;
    }​
```

But this doesn't work:

```
      $(function() {
         $("#startdateMyWorkouts").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
         $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").css('display','none');
    });
```

Comment: check my modified answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using, `.datepicker("hide")`. you could do it in an event. Here you are doing it in document load

By the way if you want this to happen in an event use the following way,

```
$(function() {
    $("#startdateMyWorkouts").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
           $("#datefilterMyWorkouts").change(function()) { // your select change event
              return false; // to hide the datepicker
           });
        } 
    });
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work... but I don't want to hide entire datapicker, just .ui-datepicker-calendar class.

Comment: at which event do u want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that when you try to hide the element, the Datepicker Plugin is still creating the elements, so there is nothing to hide! 
The Code is fine!

Datepicker API Doc maybe has something for you! :

```
hide()
```

Close a previously opened date picker.

This method does not accept any arguments.

Code examples:

Invoke the hide method:

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "hide" );
```

Comment: It is the same thing "onchange" event for select element.

Comment: Only ui-datepicker-calendar class I want to set hidden.